# Where can I find the image of MY Camelopardalis?

Tags: observational-astronomy

In this [news article](http://zeenews.india.com/news/sci-tech/astronomers-spot-two-stars-beginning-to-merge-to-create-a-megastar_1513391.html), it says

> The image captured by the telescope at the Calar Alto Observatory in southern Spain, reveal the physical properties of each of the stars including temperature and shape.

I Googled to see the actual image but unfortunately all are graphical images.So can I see the actual image as captured by the Calar Alto Observatory?

Answer (score 3):

The work on [the recent paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.5575v1.pdf) was done using spectra and light curves, not via direct imaging.  There may not be a good image to view.  I checked the [Hubble Legacy Archive](http://hla.stsci.edu/hlaview.html#) and could not find a Hubble image of the object.

Comment: Fig. 6 is a "representative" drawing, but I think you're right that there's no direct imaging.